# Is it possible to show Custom List Item on a listview in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React Native app, what I was trying is to create a Custom ListView Item just like android where I can use TextViews, ImageView etc as a placeholder. The thing is I didn't find anything yet that could help me.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaZV4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listview is deprecated. Do try using Flatlist for the same, Do check out my code in expo snack [expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/S128seuZI) wher it resembles some part, exact design you can make of your own,

below is the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text,Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Image style={{height:50,width:50}} source={{uri:'https://source.unsplash.com/random'}} />
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.title2}>{title}</Text>
      <Image style={{height:15,width:15,marginLeft:20}} source={{uri:'https://source.unsplash.com/random'}} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    flexDirection:'row'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 10,
  },
  title2:{
    fontSize:12 , marginLeft:10
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, this is what I am looking for. One more question does this supports all screen sizes ?